# Convert sync function to async got "This construct may only be used within computation expressions"?

Tags: f#

How to convert the following code to async ones?

```
let m1 x = x * 2
let m2 s =
    let l = [1..10]
    l |> List.iter(fun x -> printfn "%d" (m1 x))
    s // the function returns something
```

The following will get an error.

```
let n1 x = async { return x * 2 }
let n2 s =
    async {
        let l = [1..10] // l will be generated by s
        l |> List.iter(fun x -> 
            let y = do! n1 x // ERROR: This construct may only be used within computation expressions
            printfn "%d" y)
        return s
    }
```

The following will get rid of the error but it calls `n1` synchronously.

```
let n2 s =
    async {
        let l = [1..10]
        l |> List.iter(fun x -> 
            async {
                let! y = n1 x
                printfn "%d" y
            } |> Async.RunSynchronously)
        return s
    }
```

`n2` will be called in a `List.iter` in another function. So at the outermost level, I want to do `Async.Parallel` for the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for .. in .. do` expression:

```
let n1 x = async { return x * 2 }
let n2 s =
    async {
        let l = [1..10] // l will be generated by s
        for x in l do
            let! y = n1 x
            printfn "%d" y
        return s
    }
```